# Error: `useTheme` must be used within `NativeBaseConfigProvider`

Tags: node.js, npm

In my project I experienced the above error

The error explanation :

This error is located at:

```
in Container

in ProductContainer (created by App)

in RCTView (created by View)

in View (created by App)

in App (created by ExpoRoot)

in ExpoRoot

in RCTView (created by View)

in View (created by AppContainer)

in RCTView (created by View)

in View (created by AppContainer)

in AppContainer
```

ProductContainer.js:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native'

import { Container, Header, Icon, Item, Input, Text } from 'native-base';

import ProductList from './ProductList';

const data = require('../../assets/data/products.json');

const ProductContainer = () => {

```
const [products, setProducts ] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    setProducts(data);

    return () => {

        setProducts([])

    }

}, [])

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {

      flex: 1,

      backgroundColor: '#fff',

      alignItems: 'center',

      justifyContent: 'center',

    }

})

return (

    <Container>

        <Header searchBar rounded>

        </Header>

        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>Product Container</Text>

            <View style={styles.listContainer}>

            <FlatList 

                data={products}

                numColumns={2}

                renderItem={({item}) => <ProductList 

                key={item.brand}

                item={item}/>}

                keyExtractor={item => item.brand}

            />

        </View>

    </View> 

    </Container>
    
)
```

}

export default ProductContainer;

Comment: I'm getting the same error when running Jest tests. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this error from this github issue: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4303.

Apparently the problem is that you need to wrap app elements in `<NativeBaseProvider>`.

In this example you can see how the native base provider wraps all other providers, if the `<NativeBaseProvider>` is not at the top, it will throw the error: `` useTheme must be used within `NativeBaseConfigProvider ``

```
export default function App() {
    return (
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <AuthProvider>
            <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
            <StatusBar />
          </AuthProvider>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Container>
    <Header searchBar rounded>
    </Header>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Product Container</Text>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        <FlatList 
            data={products}
            numColumns={2}
            renderItem={({item}) => <ProductList 
            key={item.brand}
            item={item}/>}
            keyExtractor={item => item.brand}
        />
    </View>
</View> 
</Container>
```

wrap all these Container tag and its contents inside...

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is happening in Testing you can simply pass initialWindowMetrics to NativeBaseProvider in your tests.

```
const inset = {
  frame: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 },
  insets: { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
};

<NativeBaseProvider initialWindowMetrics={inset}>
  {children}
</NativeBaseProvider>;
```